# Running python code converted to C on IAR

Tags: python, iar

I running a code that written on C and compiled with IAR for few years on nRF52832.
Now i have a task to implement a new algorithm on embbeded but it was written with python.

Does someone had a good experience with converting python to C?
Converter to pure C, without GCC references.

Thanks

Comment: Python and C have completely different memory management. Automated conversion from one language to another completely different language to embedded environment will likely end up with supbar results. I recommend doing the conversion manually.